# passing a variable in SOQL select statement with python and simple-salesforce

Tags: soql, datetime, python, simple-salesforce

I am trying to pass a variable into SOQL statement, I am using simple_salesforce library. I only need to grab the data when CreateDate of the Opportunity is > than yesterday, yesterday's date is saved in `last_run_day` variable. Below is my code:

```
yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)
last_run_date = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+"T"+"%H:%M:%S"+"Z")

sf_data = sf.query_all("SELECT ID, Name FROM Opportunity where probability > 0 AND CreatedDate > '%s' AND AdPoint_Id__c <> NULL ORDER BY AdPoint_Id__c" % last_run_date)
print(sf_data)
```

Gives me an error: field 'CreatedDate' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes", 'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'

Comment: You can either remove the quotes surrounding `%s` otherwise the date will be considered as String, which is not correct OR simply write `where CreatedDate > YESTERDAY`. See date literals here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: Perfect, that actually worked and there was no need to construct a variable last_run_date, Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Added it as an answer.

Comment: Side note - fstrings make your strings more readable in many cases than old-style `%` formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can either remove the quotes surrounding `%s` otherwise the date will be considered as String, which is not correct OR simply write `where CreatedDate > YESTERDAY`.

Please see date literals here.o https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm